# How can I make the length of the texture bar equal when pressing and releasing the left shift in unity and c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to draw the texture bar after I press the left shift to show the player's sprint and after releasing the left shift key the bar will refill quickly. The problem is I want to delay the bar one second before refilling (AFTER RELEASING THE LEFT SHIFT), but when I did it using a coroutine as follows :

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
stamina += Time.deltaTime;
```

the length of the bar became longer.

Below is a screenshot after pressing the left shift:
[image]

Below is a screenshot after releasing the left shift:
[image]

the code is below:

```
float stamina = 5, maxStamina = 5;
     float walkSpeed, runSpeed;
     bool isRunning;
     Rect staminaRect;
     Texture2D staminaTexture;
 
 
     void Start () {
         walkSpeed = moveSpeed;
         runSpeed = walkSpeed * 1.5f; //1.5 multiplier to sprint instead of 3x
     }
 
 
  void FixedUpdate() {
         StartCoroutine(SprintPlayer());
     }
 
 
     void SetRunning(bool isRunning)
     {
         this.isRunning = isRunning;
         moveSpeed = isRunning ? runSpeed : walkSpeed;
     }
     
 
 IEnumerator SprintPlayer()
     {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
         {
             SetRunning(true);
             staminaRect = new Rect(Screen.width / 10, Screen.height * 9 / 10, Screen.width / 3, Screen.height / 50);
             staminaTexture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
             staminaTexture.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.white);
             staminaTexture.Apply();
         }
 
         if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
         {
             SetRunning(false);
         }
 
         if (isRunning)
         {
             stamina -= Time.deltaTime;
             if (stamina < 0)
             {
                 stamina = 0;
                 SetRunning(false);
             }
         }
         else if (stamina < maxStamina)
         {
             yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
             stamina += Time.deltaTime;
         }
     }
 
     void OnGUI()
     {
         float ratio = stamina / maxStamina;
         float rectWidth = ratio * Screen.width / 3;
         staminaRect.width = rectWidth;
         GUI.DrawTexture(staminaRect, staminaTexture);
     }
```

any suggestions please about how can I make the length of the texture bar equal when pressing and releasing the left shift?

Comment: [Mathf.Clamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) it to your maximum value?

Comment: No, I didn't use it before

Comment: Seems like a pretty good use case: `stamina = Mathf.Clamp(stamina, 0, maxStamina);`

Comment: Only one way to find out!

Comment: I have added it in the else block after waitforseconds as follows ` yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            stamina = Mathf.Clamp(stamina, 0, maxStamina);
            stamina += Time.deltaTime;
` is this ok?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253373/discussion-between-jay-and-saad).

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit the upper value of `stamina`. But also it seems like you're missunderstanding how coroutines work. You really don't want to be starting one every fixed update... and you dont need to be using fixed update for this at all.

Something like this should do the trick

```
Coroutine staminaRecoveryCoroutine;

// don't look for input in fixed update
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        if(staminaRecoveryCoroutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(staminaRecoveryCoroutine);
            staminaRecoveryCoroutine = null; // just to be explicit
        }

        stamina = Mathf.Clamp(stamina - Time.deltaTime, 0, maxStamina);
    }
    else
    {
        if(staminaRecoveryCoroutine == null)
            staminaRecoveryCoroutine = StartCoroutine(staminaRecoveryCoroutine());
    }

    UpdateStaminaDisplay();

}

private IEnumerator StaminaRecoveryCoroutine()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    while(stamina < maxStamina)
    {
        stamina = Mathf.Clamp(stamina + Time.deltaTime, 0, maxStamina);
        yield return null; // wait for next frame
    }
}
```